# Instagram removed subscription for tag and when resubscribing it disappears even with successful response

Tags: api, instagram

I am running an application using Instagram's RealTime API and when I subscribe to a tag initially all is working fine, I can see for sure my response times are all within 100ms back to instagram but after about an hour, hour and a half they randomly delete my tag subscription.  I check and I am not rate limited so I setup something to check my subscriptions every 10 minutes and if the tag I was subscribed to isn't returned from instagram to re-subscribe it.  When running that I get back a response that it is subscribed -

```
{ object: 'tag',
  object_id: '...',
  aspect: 'media',
  callback_url: 'http://...',
  type: 'subscription',
  id: '4479168' }
```

but then when I check my subscriptions again using the API Console it shows there are no subscriptions.

Does anyone have any idea why Instagram is deleting my subscription automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Did you validate/confirm the subscription? You didn't mention doing it in your question so that leads me to think that maybe it's timing out after not being confirmed?

According to the [API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#) a `POST` to make any subscription will trigger a `GET` to your `callback_url` that will include:

- hub.mode - This will be set to "subscribe"
- hub.challenge - This will be set to a random string that your callback URL will need to echo back in order to verify you'd like to subscribe.
- hub.verify_token - This will be set to whatever verify_token passed in with the subscription request.

The example URL given is:

```
http://your-callback.com/url/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.verify_token=myVerifyToken
```

After parsing that callback you have to send a response including the `hub.challenge` value and you should have a lasting subscription.

Comment: Yes if you don't validate then the creation method fails, plus they don't send updates since the subscription isn't created. In my case, the subscriptions get created just fine and work for a few minutes, then stop.

Comment: Yes the subscriptions are definitely validated otherwise they wouldn't send a response back with the subscription id.  Over my course of testing, the only way I can get it to work somewhat reliably is to check my subscriptions every x minutes. If the subscription isn't there resubscribe.  After running for so long eventually my subscriptions stick.  I don't know why I would need to do this but when running something for a long time (days) it seems to work fine then.  Also with each subscription I store the min_id of posts so when I say give me the latest after X it picks up where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this happens when Instagram decides you are not responding fast enough. I noticed 8 separate IPs posting the exact same subscription info (identical HTTP requests) and my app apparently has some transient lag issues. It appears that if responses are not sent immediately (100s of ms) then Instagram silently deletes the subscription and there's no way to find out.

Solution was to dump the subscription model and just poll them instead.